# Clarification on interpreting Wald's test and Likelihood ratio tests

Tags: r, logistic, multinomial-distribution, likelihood-ratio

I am running multinomial logistic regression analysis on my data.  The response variable is the number of calves produced each year (0,1, or 2).  I am trying to evaluate the influence of the *X* variables on the odds of producing a calf.  My *X* variables are predation risk (WR; continuous), age of mother (age; categorical or continuous), time (wolf; categorical).

First, I have 4 different age classification schemes (i only show 2) - I want to know which one of the age of mother would be "best" to use. I could use it as continuous variable - or as categories based on biological reasoning for senescence in older moose (old ladies don't invest in reproduction as much).  So, I thought I would use a likelihood ratio test.

```
library(mlogit)

modata.model1 <- mlogit(no.C ~ 1 | 1, data=modata, reflevel="1", na.action = na.omit) 
modata.model2 <- mlogit(no.C ~ 1 | age, data=modata, reflevel="1", na.action = na.omit) 
modata.model3 <- mlogit(no.C ~ 1 | age2, data=modata, reflevel="1", na.action = na.omit)
```

---

```
 lrtest(modata.model2,modata.model3)

Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: no.C ~ 1 | age
Model 2: no.C ~ 1 | age2
  #Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
1   4 -213.22                         
2   4 -207.57  0 11.309  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

QUESTION: to interpret this output - there was a significant difference in the loglikelihood when we comparing the continuous age to a categorical age with 2 classes.  The loglik is smaller for model 1 and therefore it would be better to use? Or do I have that backwards?

Next I was going to use the Walds test to evaluate nested models.  To see if the addition of a variable was worth it.

```
modata.model7 <- mlogit(no.C ~ 1 | age+WR, data=modata, reflevel="1", na.action = na.omit) 

modata.model8 <- mlogit(no.C ~ 1 | age+WR+wolf, data=modata, reflevel="1", na.action = na.omit)
```

---

```
Wald test

Model 1: no.C ~ 1 | age + WR
Model 2: no.C ~ 1 | age + WR + wolf
  Res.Df Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
1    244                     
2    242  2 0.5828     0.7472
```

QUESTION: this tells me that there is no significant improvement when there is an additional variable of wolf added??  So, then I can use the smaller model or do I use the one with the smaller Res.DF?

In addition to confirming my interpretations of the results I have 2 side questions...

1)to get the null model for `mlogit` library - is my `modata.model1` correct?  I want the intercept only model to compare against.

2) Hosmer and Lemshow suggest by getting Wald values to get significance levels for each coefficient - in mlogit, thats the same as using `summary(model)` and there they provide the t-values with p instead of needing to do an additional Walds test? (NOTE in the below model i use 2 category age class instead of continuous)

```
summary(modata.model8)

Call:
mlogit(formula = no.C ~ 1 | age2 + WR + wolf, data = modata, 
    na.action = na.omit, reflevel = "1", method = "nr", print.level = 0)

Frequencies of alternatives:
    1     0     2 
0.652 0.244 0.104 

nr method
6 iterations, 0h:0m:0s 
g'(-H)^-1g = 7.4E-06 
successive function values within tolerance limits 

Coefficients :
              Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)   
0:(intercept)  0.38730    0.40144  0.9648 0.334657   
2:(intercept) -2.40317    1.04546 -2.2987 0.021523 * 
0:age21       -1.39607    0.43989 -3.1737 0.001505 **
2:age21        0.53952    1.07275  0.5029 0.615012   
0:WR          -1.46584    0.64797 -2.2622 0.023686 * 
2:WR          -0.19214    0.60856 -0.3157 0.752206   
0:wolf1        0.56055    0.63292  0.8857 0.375797   
2:wolf1        0.42642    0.72375  0.5892 0.555744   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Log-Likelihood: -203.11
McFadden R^2:  0.053606 
Likelihood ratio test : chisq = 23.009 (p.value = 0.00079359)
```